# How to display this JSON in tableView using Alamofire

Tags: swift, tableview, alamofire

How i can display this JSON in tableView with Alamofire? I dont know how it add to array and how create the struct for this JSON.

```
{
  "list" : [
      "main" : {
        "humidity" : 47,
        "temp_min" : 27,
        "temp_max" : 32,
        "temp" : 30.43,
        "pressure" : 1012
      },
      "name" : "Tivat",
      "clouds" : {
        "all" : 20
      },
      "coord" : {
        "lon" : 18.699999999999999,
        "lat" : 42.439999999999998
      },
      "id" : 3189073,
      "weather" : [
        {
          "main" : "Clouds",
          "icon" : "02d",
          "description" : "few clouds",
          "id" : 801
        }
      ],
      "dt" : 1531914017,
      "sys" : {
        "sunset" : 1531937890,
        "sunrise" : 1531884257,
        "message" : 0.0023,
        "id" : 5453,
        "type" : 1,
        "country" : "ME"
      },
      "visibility" : 10000,
      "wind" : {
        "deg" : 300,
        "speed" : 7.7000000000000002
      }
    }
  ],
  "cnt" : 1
}
```

Need display name of city and temperature. I know, how it display on URLSession, but i want to use Alamofire.

Comment: Alamofire is used for sending and receiving http requests, if all you're wanting to do is display that JSON in a tableview, you don't need Alamofire, but you do need a basic understanding of Swift Tableviews and Delegates. There are a million tutorials for this. https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/ is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire is not for displaying JSON data. You will need to parse your JSON to a Swift object, [QuickType](https://quicktype.io/?l=swift#l=swift) can help you do that easily. You will then need to use that object to populate a table view with the data you want inside the dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:) function, multiple tutorials are available to help you do that.